# Brute Force Permutation Swapping

Tags: c++, algorithm, brute-force

I've been working on a brute force algorithm to generate all permutations of a given set. Eventually, I want to feed each of these permutations into a nxn matrix to test if it is a valid magic square or not. 
--I KNOW THAT THERE IS A WAY TO GENERATE A MAGIC SQUARE EASILY--
That is not what I want to do, though. I'm focusing on the brute force aspect of it.

For a set of 3 elements, it works wonderfully. However, once I use 4 or more elements, I lose out on a few permutations. Just from looking at the output of 4, I am missing 7 permutations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


//ms = magic square
//n = size
void perm(int ms[], int n) {
    int pivot = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int pivBit = 1;
    int fin = 0;
    int hold = 0;

    //While we are not finished
    while (fin == 0)  {
        //Incriment the index
        ++index;
        if (index >= n) {
            index = 0;
        }
        //if index is equal to the pivot
        if (index == pivot) {
            //Is this the first time visiting the pivot?
            if (pivBit == 0) {
                //Are we at the beginning again?
                if (index == 0 && pivot == 0)
                {
                    fin = 1;
                }
                pivBit = 1;
                ++index;
            }
            //Second time visiting? 
            else {
                pivBit = 0;
                ++pivot;
                if (pivot >= n) {
                    pivot = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        //If we are out of bounds
        if (index >= n) {
            index = 0;
        }

        //swap
        hold = ms[index];
        ms[index] = ms[pivot];
        ms[pivot] = hold;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            cout << ms[i];
            if (i < n - 1) {
                cout << ", ";
            }
            else {
                cout << endl;
            }


        }

    }

}



int main() {

    cout << "Are you ready to brute force, my brother?" << endl;

    //Set
    int magicsquare[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int size = 4;

    perm(magicsquare, size);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

```
2 1 3 4
3 1 2 4
4 1 2 3
1 4 2 3
1 2 4 3
1 3 4 2
3 1 4 2 
3 4 1 2
3 4 2 1
2 4 3 1
2 3 4 1 
2 3 1 4
4 3 1 2
4 2 1 3
4 2 3 1
1 2 3 4
2 1 3 4
```

Looking at it, I can already see that I am missing both 1 4 3 2 and 1 3 2 4. 
Where've I gone wrong in my algorithm?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you thought about using [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) instead?

Comment: I'm translating this to another language. I just understand C++ the most, so I write everything in C++ before I translate it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki article on permutation includes a common algorithm used to produce all permutations in lexicographic order, starting with an array of sequentially increasing integers, ending with that array reversed. [wiki next permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order).

If dealing with an array of objects, you can generate an array of indices 0 through n-1 and use next permutation on the indices to produce all permutations of the array of objects.

You can also do a web search for next permutation to find similar algorithms. The recursive ones produce all permutations, but not in lexicographic order.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to generate all permutations is recursive. For each i, swap the i'th element to the 0 position.  Then recursively find all permutations of of the remaining array.

```
int buf[1000], n;  // better to wrap these in a class...

void permute(int *a, int a_len) {
  if (a_len == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", buf[i]);
    printf("\n");
  } else { 
    for (int i = 0; i < a_len; i++) { 
      swap(a, 0, i);
      permute(a + 1, a_len - 1);
      swap(a, 0, i);
    }
  }
}

void run(int buf_len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < buf_len; i++) buf[i] = i + 1;
  n = buf_len;
  permute(buf, buf_len);
}
```

This assumes no repeated elements in the original array.  It's not to hard to have it take repeated elements into account.